# How can I make this unity movement script work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make this script work, or another alternative player movement script? This basic movement script in Unity doesn't do anything when i press WASD for some reason. I am a beginner at C# and unity and I kind of need an alternative player movement script that actually works.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) 
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right);
```

Comment: One suggestion, please use `else if` instead of multiple `if`

Comment: There are many issues here ... `GetKeyDown` is only true in the first frame where the key was first pressed down ... `GetKey` is true **every frame while** that key **stays pressed** ... and then you still don't want to move frame-rate dependent with a fixed distance per frame but rather using `Time.deltaTime` in order to move with a distance per second regardless of the frame-rate

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the GetAxis("Horizontal") and GetAxis("Vertical") methods which maps wasd and arrow keys by default to help slim down your big if tree.

Below is a small example from an old unversity project of mine.

Note: the "* speed * Time.deltaTime" as this is used to help translate as time/frames move on, speed is just a multiplier in this case.

```
public float speed = 10.0f;
private float translation;
private float straffe;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    // turn off the cursor
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Input.GetAxis() is used to get the user's input
    // You can further set it on Unity. (Edit, Project Settings, Input)
    translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    straffe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(straffe, 0, translation);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
    {
        // turn on the cursor
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignore the Cursor.lockState as that was just for UI/hiding cursor from the screen as part of a Look script

Answer (score 0):

`Input.GetKeyDown` checks if you pressed the w key on that frame. You need `Input.GetKey`. That checks if you are holding

Answer (score 0):

You should use GetAxis("Horizontal") & GetAxis("Vertical");
Here is my basic code for my projects default movement:

```
    //movement
Rigidbody rb;
float xInput;
float yInput;
public float speed;
public float defSpeed;
public float sprint;
public bool isGrounded = true;
public float jump;

// Start is called before the first frame update

private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    yInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    //Things is still can't understand
    Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    float cameraRot = Camera.main.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    rb.position += Quaternion.Euler(0, cameraRot, 0) * input * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    //sprint
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) 
    {
        speed = sprint;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = defSpeed;
    }

    //jump
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, jump, 0);
        //Debug.Log("Jump!");
    }
```

Hope this helps:)